# Missing Python in LibreOffice organize macros menu

Tags: python, libreoffice, customization

I have the LibreOffice 4.0.2.2 that comes with Ubuntu 13.04. The **Tools-Macros-Organize macros** menu only shows the **LibreOffice Basic** item. I assumed I would find also Python and other languages. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223209/installing-pyuno-libreoffice-for-private-python-build) post and many other posts talk about it, but I can't find it.

Was my assumption wrong? Do I need to install something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem and have solved it by installing [`libreoffice-script-provider-python`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libreoffice-script-provider-python):

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python
```

Hope it helps.

**Update:** in order to get your scripts listed in the macro dialog, you should put them in a folder called: `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python`, as pointed out by @Mark in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now I have the Python item, but I can only run existing Python macros. I can't create new ones or edit the existing ones. Do I still miss something? Or that's the way it works? How do I create a new one?

Comment: Yes am stuck in the same place...

Comment: As fair as I know, there's no Python editing capability builtin with LibreOffice. You can edit your macros in an external editor and then save them to the appropriate path.

Answer (score 0):

Make a subdirectory python (all lowercase) inside your home directory `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts` and put your scripts there.

Comment: this does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 with LibreOffice -- scripts should instead be put in `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python` -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074770/420385